# Git ignoring directories with numerical names

Tags: git

OpenFOAM creates time directories with numeric names such as `3` or `8.941` in the root directory of a case (as described in the [OpenFOAM User Manual](http://www.openfoam.org/docs/user/case-file-structure.php)).  Since all of these directories are generated programmatically (except for the initial conditions in the `0` directory), how can I persuade git to ignore the directories?  I'm not aware of a way to relocate the time directories into a subdirectory and, even if I could, this would likely upset related processing tools such as [ParaView](http://www.paraview.org/).

Comment: Do these directories contains any files?

Comment: What about the files in these directories? Can you ignore them?

Comment: Good idea.  Yes, these directories (almost) always contain files with the same name, so I guess I could just `.gitignore` those files rather than the directories.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`.gitignore`](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) accepts [`fnmatch`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/functions/fnmatch.html) patterns, so that allows [`?`, `*`, and `\[...\]` expressions matching a single character](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_13_01).

That means you can match directories *starting* with a digit:

```
[0-9]*/
```

If this gives false positives, you'll have to use more specific patterns:

```
[0-9]/
[0-9][0-9]*/
[0-9]*.[0-9]*/
```